# Undefined variable: model2

Tags: yii2

I have 2 models that will load in one form.
But when I want to access the second model, there is error  said "Undefined variable: model2"
Please help.

This is the controller
InventoryController.php

```
public function actionInsert() {
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

    $model = new Inventory();
    $model2 = new \app\models\Unitofmeasurement();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $command = $connection->createCommand('{call usp_M_Inventory#Transaksi(:ID_Item,:Item_Name, :IDMom, :Item_Price, :ID_InvCategory,:Item_PIC1,
:Item_PIC2,:Item_active, :UserInventory, :ID_Mom, :Satuan_Beli, :Qty_Beli, :Satuan_Jual,:Qty_Jual, :ActiveMOM, :UserMOM)}');
        $ID_Item = $model->ID_Item;
        $Item_Name = $model->Item_Name;
        $IDMom = $model->IDMom;
        $Item_Price = $model->Item_Price;
        $ID_InvCategory = $model->ID_Inv_Category;
        $Item_PIC1 = $model->Item_PIC1;
        $Item_PIC2 = $model->Item_PIC2;
        $Item_active = $model->Item_active;
        $UserInventory = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;

        $ID_Mom = $model2->ID_Mom;
        $Satuan_Beli = $model2->Satuan_Beli;
        $Qty_Beli = $model2->Qty_Beli;
        $Satuan_Jual = $model2->Satuan_Jual;
        $Qty_Jual = $model2->Qty_Jual;
        $ActiveMOM = $model2->Active;
        $UserMOM = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
if ($command->execute() == 0) {
            $transaction->commit();
        } else {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            foreach ($model->getErrors() as $key => $message) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $message);
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_Item]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'model2' => $model2,
                    'model3' => $model3,
                    'model4' => $model4,
                    'model5' => $model5,
                    'model6' => $model6,
                    'model7' => $model7,
        ));
    }
```

This is Create View
 create.php

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<?=
$this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'model2' => $model2,
    'model3' => $model3,
    'model4' => $model4,
    'model5' => $model5,
    'model6' => $model6,
    'model7' => $model7,
])
?>
```

This is the form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'ID_Item')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'Item_Name')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'ID_Mom')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'Item_Price')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'ID_Inv_Category')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'Item_PIC1')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'Item_PIC2')->textInput() ?>

<?=
$form->field($model, 'Item_active')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'onText' => 'Active',
        'offText' => 'Not Active',
    ]
])
?>

<?=$form->field($model2,'ID_Mom')->textInput() ?>
```

Comment: can you  tell us file and line where error occurred

Comment: get var_export of $model2 before pass to create and in create , tell the result

Comment: Undefined variable: model2

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="inventory-create">
 
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
 
    <?=
    $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'model2' => $model2,
        'model3' => $model3,
        'model4' => $model4,
        'model5' => $model5,
        'model6' => $model6,
        'model7' => $model7,
    ])
    ?>
 
</div>

Comment: is $model3 is working? pls show your url like `localhost/yourapp/controller/action`

Comment: $model3 also Undefined variable: model3
the url http://localhost:81/posrkidev/web/index.php/inventory/create

Comment: @Allegra  seems that someone downvote sistematically my answer to your question .. in this way i can't help you in the best way .. the problem is that you are trying  to using th $model ....$model7 but you have defined only the var $model and $model2 ... probably there is somthings wrong in your approach ..

Comment: Actually I use all the 7 models, but I just write it here only until $model2 because it will too long to write all here @scaisEdge

Comment: tell me exactly where the error and at which line the error appear..please  ... any way copy , paste  and formatting the code .. seems not so loong to me ..

Comment: the error is Undefined variable: model2 in create.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is: `localhost:81/posrkidev/web/index.php/inventory/create`

you should put all the code from

```
public function actionInsert() {
...
}
```

To action create:

```
 public function actionCreate() {
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

    $model = new Inventory();
    $model2 = new \app\models\Unitofmeasurement();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $command = $connection->createCommand('{call usp_M_Inventory#Transaksi(:ID_Item,:Item_Name, :IDMom, :Item_Price, :ID_InvCategory,:Item_PIC1,
:Item_PIC2,:Item_active, :UserInventory, :ID_Mom, :Satuan_Beli, :Qty_Beli, :Satuan_Jual,:Qty_Jual, :ActiveMOM, :UserMOM)}');
        $ID_Item = $model->ID_Item;
        $Item_Name = $model->Item_Name;
        $IDMom = $model->IDMom;
        $Item_Price = $model->Item_Price;
        $ID_InvCategory = $model->ID_Inv_Category;
        $Item_PIC1 = $model->Item_PIC1;
        $Item_PIC2 = $model->Item_PIC2;
        $Item_active = $model->Item_active;
        $UserInventory = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;

        $ID_Mom = $model2->ID_Mom;
        $Satuan_Beli = $model2->Satuan_Beli;
        $Qty_Beli = $model2->Qty_Beli;
        $Satuan_Jual = $model2->Satuan_Jual;
        $Qty_Jual = $model2->Qty_Jual;
        $ActiveMOM = $model2->Active;
        $UserMOM = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
if ($command->execute() == 0) {
            $transaction->commit();
        } else {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            foreach ($model->getErrors() as $key => $message) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $message);
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_Item]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'model2' => $model2,
                    'model3' => $model3,
                    'model4' => $model4,
                    'model5' => $model5,
                    'model6' => $model6,
                    'model7' => $model7,
        ));
    }
```

or try this url: `localhost:81/posrkidev/web/index.php/inventory/insert`